# How can I implement faceted search with Wordpress 3.x?

Tags: search, navigation

I would like to allow visitors to a site to search for posts based on various attributes (categories, tags, custom fields).

I have tried using Solr, but this doesn't appear to work.

I tried using the MySolrServer plugins for a local instance of Solr and a hosted instance, but the plugin doesn't appear to work.

I also tried using Solr for Wordpress, but the plugin wouldn't enable.

I don't want to use something like Taxonomy Drill-down.

Bearing those points in mind, how can I now try to implement true faceted search that will enable site visitors to search for posts based on attributes?

Comment: What "various attributes" are you talking about? Tags? Categories? Custom fields?

Comment: Pretty much - I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: What about Relevanssi http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/ According to their key features, `Search comments, tags, categories and custom fields.`. It also provides more relevant results.

Comment: Thanks, Christine. I've had a quick look and it doesn't appear to provide a facility of faceted search - just enhanced search across various elements of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of my favorite ways to do this is to use the [Factious](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facetious/) plugin. It is still fairly basic and only has a Sidebar widget by default. However, it has an extenable API(ish thing) that lets you write code to place it elsewhere.

The reasons why I like it are this:

- Written by people who know what they are doing (Code for the People WordPress VIP Partners)
- Simple
- Keeps search within WordPress. For me this is huge I'm always skeptical about using third party services.
- Extendable

Not sure if that is what you are looking for but none the less it should be a tiny bit easier than writing custom `WP_Query` and will be a good "get your feet wet" into WordPress' Objects.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/fantastic-elasticsearch/) that does both faceted search and provides better search capabilities. It doesn't do everything and the kitchen sink, but it is a good starting point (uses ElasticSearch).

Comment: This is basically "link only". Please provide some detail about what your plugin does and doesn't do why you think it solves the OP's problem.